# nodelet: Publisher subscriber

Tags: roscpp, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen the basic working of the nodelets and even read the instruction how to port your class to nodelet. But I don't know how to make my publisher subscriber nodes into nodelet. Once of the instruction is delete the main() and put the constructor into the init(). So then where does the publisher while loop go then ? and where is my subscriber supposed to do the callback ? I am completely confused. Does anyone have a minimum working example for publisher subscriber nodelets ? Or any tips on how to do this task ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247041/nodelet:-publisher-subscriber/) by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This book below has some good examples:

Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming
By Lentin Joseph

To answer my own question in short, there are no while loops or spin() and spinOnce() this is taken care of by the nodelet manager.

---

Originally posted by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) with karma: 54 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0